# hibernate.cfg.xml not found (intellij/maven)

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

So I am running a hibernate Project in intellij but since I added a module-info hibernate isn't finding the config.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS4p0.png)

As you can see above the config is in resources where it's supposed to be in a maven project.
Removing the module-info doesnt change anything.
This is my module-info:

```
module ProjektRechnungsprogramm {
requires java.persistence;
requires java.sql;
requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
requires java.naming;
requires net.bytebuddy;
requires org.hibernate.commons.annotations;}
```

Even if I try getClass.getResource("hibernate.cfg.xml") it is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

You have placed your config in utils directory so get resource using

getClass.getResource("Utils/hibernate.cfg.xml")

Comment: Yeah was just for testing purposes. It doesnt make a difference if its on root or in the directory Utils. It shouldn't even make a diffrence for getResource aswell if I remember correctly

Comment: @NielYorck are you able to access config file using getClass.getResource("Utils/hibernate.cfg.xml")

Comment: No. Returns null aswell.

Comment: @NielYorck if you can add code in question, I can help you.

Comment: It fails on this line:
registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
Configure should automatically find the config